# How to mock a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, mocking

Let's say I have a function like this:

```
def do_something(dict_obj):
   # access to the dict_obj then do some stuff
   eg.
   if dict_obj['doors']:
      do_something_with_doors()
   map_car_make(dict_obj['make'])
   ...

   if dict_obj['is_active']:
        do_something_else()
```

I want to mock the `dict_obj` to have `is_active` element and don't care the rest, how do I do that?

Comment: Why bother mocking a simple data structure at all? Why not `dict_obj['is_active'] = True`? Usually it's _behavior_ that should be stubbed out, not data.

Comment: Also, if you don't care about the values inside, you can always use `collections.defaultdict`

Comment: @MattBall because there are other logic in the function to make use of other elements in dict_obj, see updated code

Comment: Since MagicMock does not provide this functionality out of the box, I think going with the suggestions in the other comments is usually better for readability. Using a defaultdict is still possible in your example by adding `dict_obj['make'] = MagicMock()`

Comment: I've got a similar problem but the mock needs dict-like behaviour, plus *additional* method calls that do *not* appear on a normal dict that *also* need to return different mocks... aahh @Guido_Tarsia 's answer works like this.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

***How to mock a dictionary in Python*** is a good/direct question someone else can search, so:

1. I suggest [MagicMock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.MagicMock) instead of Mock
2. Overload the `__getitem__`

```py
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

m = MagicMock()
d = {'key_1': 'value'}
m.__getitem__.side_effect = d.__getitem__

# dict behaviour
m['key_1'] # => 'value'
m['key_2'] # => raise KeyError

# mock behaviour
m.foo(42)
m.foo.assert_called_once_with(43) # => raise AssertionError
```

Related Questions:

- [How to let MagicMock behave like a dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30340170/how-to-let-magicmock-behave-like-a-dict)
- [Understanding __getitem__ method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627405/understanding-getitem-method)

=== EDIT ===

As a function for direct copy/pasting

```py
def mock_dict(d):
  m = MagicMock()
  m.__getitem__.side_effect = d.__getitem__
  return m
```

Comment: if you are using typechecking, make sure to also set `mock.__class__ = dict`

Answer (score 13):

For anyone coming across this later, there is also [`mock.patch.dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch.dict) which can be used as a context manager, decorator, or class decorator.

For example:

```py
from mock import patch

foo = {}
@patch.dict(foo, {"is_active": True})
def test():
    assert foo['is_active'] == True
```

Or to mock `os.environ` which is how I came across this question:

```py
import os
from mock import patch

@patch.dict("os.environ", {"FOO": "BAR"})
def test_env():
    assert os.environ['FOO'] == "BAR"
```

Comment: Note: If you need to mock empty dict, don't forget to set `clear=True` parameter in `@patch.dict(...)` to ensure the mock dict is wiped first.

Comment: You can use `unittest.mock` if you do not wish to depend on `mock` external library and are using Python 3.3+

Answer (score 5):

You can use this to make a mock behave like a dictionary:

```
mock = mocker.MagicMock()
mock.__getitem__.side_effect = lambda x: getattr(mock, x)
```

With that code `mock['some_property']` equals to `mock.some_property`.
This way you can still use your autogenerated `Mock`s so useful for assertions, which is why I didn't like the accepted answer.

If you still need to access the methods of the dictionary then the code will need further work.

Comment: No, wait, this might be the answer for me. So the mock here will imitate dictionary behaviour, automatically return new mocks for any key accessed in the 'dictionary' and will *also* support additional methods tacked on that are not in normal dictionaries. Just going to try this... yeah that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dict.get](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm) method to return the default value of your choice that can mock the existence of is_active entry.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood a question, but what about just default dict?

You can safely access any keys now.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(str, is_active=True)

... # Perform code calls
# And check it
assert dd['is_active'] == True
```