# Cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Tags: python, spyder

I need to use `__getitem__` for all 7 arguments in my class but `__getitem__` won't let me so I tried to use a `tuple` but I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

What should I do?

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    name,author,category,Isbn_number,printing_house,date,number_of_order = key
    return (self.name,self.author,self.category,self.Isbn_number,self.printing_house,self.date,self.number_of_order)
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627405/understanding-getitem-method

Comment: I dont get it ı mean ı understand(kinda) how getitem works but ı need to use getitem method for getting 7 arg in key cause ı want tu use a sorting function for my objects so ı need my objects to return as keys

Comment: i recommend just creating your own custom `get` method, no need to pass in any arguments to the method nor even follow the python `__getitem__` convention.

Comment: but ı dont know how yo use a get method but ı tried and then ı figured out my args are all str so dict.get cant receive them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a **getitem** that returns the contents of each of the member variables given a key that is the same as the name of that member, you could have the class store the information in a dict and have your get_item return from that dict. E.g.:

```
class Book():
    def __init__(self, name='Jud', author='Jill', category='YA'):
        self.elements = {'name': name, 'author': author, 'category': category}

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.elements[key]
```

Then with an instance of the class you should be able to do things like:

```
book = Book()
book['name']
book['author']
```