# Get access to numpy with a dictionary lookup style but remain numpy array operations

Tags: python, numpy

I want to construct a class inheriting from the numpy.ndarray, so that it can do normal operations as a numpy array(+, -, *, /,...). The only thing I want to change is that the way we access the items in our Data. For example:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
class Data(np.ndarray):
    """
    Something magical here 
    """

img = np.asarray(Image.open('lena.jpg'))
data = img.view(Data)
data['Red'] #equivalent to img[:,:,0]
normalized_data = data/255. #normalize the data
```

Can anyone help me solve this? Thanks and kind regards

Comment: For a start I'd just a write a function to do the named selection.  Latter it could be cast as a Class with its own `get_item` method.  Look at `np.lib.index_tricks` for examples.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to override the __getitem__ method. Here is another question which may provide some intuition: [Understanding __getitem__ method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627405/understanding-getitem-method).

Link to the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__

If you want to change you you set the values, you override __setitem__

An example:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    """ Controls how values are 'gotten'. """
    if key == 'red':
        return self.data[:,:,0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better off writing your class from scratch, rather than by extending `numpy.ndarray`

My reasons:

1. Since you will be working with non-numeric indices, you are probably going to restrict yourself to 1-dimensional structures. Which means you will be completely ignoring all the multi-dimensional capabilities of `numpy.ndarray`s.
2. `numpy.ndarray` comes with some restrictions such as the fact that the elements must all be of uniform byte-size. Those restrictions may not suit you.

Also, you you might want to take a look at [structured arrays of numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.rec.html), as they can also be indexed with non-numeric indexes (well, in a certain limited sense, actually -- please go through the examples given there).

Just curious about your **desired functionality and semantics**: In numpy, if `x` and `y` are two 1d numpy arrays of the same length, you are allowed to compare them with `x == y`. On the other hand, if `data_1` and `data_2` are two of **your** arrays, having the same length of `3`, they might still be indexed differently. `data_1` might be indexed with the index values `'red'`, `'green'`, and `'blue'`, while `data_2` might be indexed with values `'high'`, `'medium'`, `'low'`. In both cases, the number of valid indices is `3`, so, in a sense, both `data_1` and `data_2` are of the same length of 3. But then, would you consider it valid to compare them with `data_1 == data_2`? What about the array of booleans resulting from the comparison? Would you index the boolean array with `'red'`, `'green'`, and `'blue'`, or with `'high'`, `'medium'`, `'low'`?