# How do I interpret this notation?

Tags: python, pandas

How and why does the notation **s[s]** work?

I'm taking one of the micro-courses from kaggle.com and they use the notation s[s] as shown below. I have not seen that before.
X_train is a pandas DataFrame.

Is it a list slicing itself? Would someone help clarify this?

```py
s = (X_train.dtypes == 'object') ## assigns True to variables == 'object'
object_cols = list(s[s].index)
```

```py
> s

Type              True
Method            True
Regionname        True
Rooms            False
Distance         False
Postcode         False
Bedroom2         False
Bathroom         False
Landsize         False
Lattitude        False
Longtitude       False
Propertycount    False
dtype: bool
```

```py
> s[s]

Type          True
Method        True
Regionname    True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: This works because `s` is a boolean array (eh. Series to be technically correct. but you get the idea), and is not something that would just work in every case. this is same as passing `s[some_boolean_array]` in this special case.

Comment: It is like list slicing. The `[]` works because DataFrames ans Series have the [`__getitem__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627405/understanding-getitem-method/43627975) method. What you have is pretty much saying that columns `Type, Method, Regionname` have `dtypes == object`. [Boolean indexing on DataFrames or Series](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/boolean-indexing-in-pandas/)

Comment: The point is that `s` is not a list, it's a pandas dataframe. One of the main features of pandas is that you can filter them in many complex ways. This includes using a df as an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas DataFrames allow you to [index using boolean arrays](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) which is how `s` is being used inside `[]`. The value of the Series is `True` or `False` as you can see, so we're selecting the values of `s` where `s` is `True`. The purpose of this code is to get columns where the datatype is `object`, you can do it with the function [`pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) instead:

```py
list(X_train.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is quite complicated.

X_train is a pandas data frame.

X_train.dtypes is returning a pandas Series, where the index (name of each row) is equal to the column name.

We now do == on the Series which returns a new series, with the value true or false. So it looks like:

`a  True
b False
c True`

Now we get to the x[x] which says to remove the 'false' values, giving a new Series:

`a True
c True`

Now we do .index and turn it into a list to give

`['a', 'c' ]`