# How does the following code create a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

On Kaggle this page(https://www.kaggle.com/alexisbcook/categorical-variables)
there's this section of code

```
s = (X_train.dtypes == 'object')
object_cols = list(s[s].index)
```

what is s (what kind of object is it) and how does s[s].index work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56957574/how-do-i-interpret-this-notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take this `DataFrame`:

```
In [2]: X_train = pd.DataFrame([("f", 2)])

In [3]: X_train
Out[3]:
   0  1
0  f  2
```

the first line `s = (X_train.dtypes == 'object')` creates a series which indicates whether each column in `X_train` is of the `object` type (here it is a `str`, in particular):

```
In [4]: s = (X_train.dtypes == 'object')

In [5]: s
Out[5]:
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```

the second line merely selects the column names that have the `True` bool in Series `s` and returns a list of those columns. This notation uses a trick called *boolean array indexing* which allows filtering a `pandas` object by an boolean iterable, which is `s` in our case:

```
In [7]: object_cols = list(s[s].index)

In [8]: object_cols
Out[8]: [0]
```