# Can @property behave like a dictionary with caching?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, caching, properties

I am trying to let a class `Foo` have a `@property` named `bars` that behaves like a Python Dictionary where we can access the values in `bars` using keys and `[` `]`:

```
foo = Foo()
foo.bars['hello']
```

The reason for using the `@property` decorator is to allow caching of the key values on first access:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self._bars = {}

    @property
    def bars(self, key):    # <--- looks like this function signature doesnt work
        if key not in self._bars.keys():
            self._bars[key] = hash(key)    # cache computation results on first access
        return self._bars[key]
```

Unfortunately, the above code leads to the error:

```
TypeError: bars() missing 1 required positional argument: 'key'
```

Is it possible to accomplish this using `@property`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding \_\_getitem\_\_ method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627405/understanding-getitem-method)

Comment: @Samwise The solutions in the linked question can help us implement access using `foo['hello']`, but not `foo.bars['hello']`, based on my limited understanding of Python

Comment: Make `bars` an object which implements `__getitem__` with the appropriate caching and then make it a property/attribute of `foo`.

Comment: @AthenaWisdom Why not just use a method?

Comment: @ekhumoro Trying to avoid altering existing code which uses an uncached dictionary by keeping the same syntax when using the cached dictionary. I think Samwise's suggestion works.

Comment: @AthenaWisdom The property decorator is no help at all. You need to create a custom class that implements the required behaviour and assign it to `bar`.

Comment: @ekhumoro Perfect, thank you