# How do I define an array class in Python?

Tags: python, class

I want to define a point, then define an array of three points as a class. Given the definition below, I can do this and it works:

```
a = [POINT(0,0) for i in range(4)]
```

but I want to be able to do this:

```
a = THREEPOINTS()
```

and then do this:

```
a[2].x = 7
a[2].y = 3
```

My attempt is below but it doesn't work. Is there a way to define a class that is an array?

```
class POINT:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class THREEPOINTS:
    def __init__(self):
        self = [POINT(0,0) for i in range(4)]
```

Comment: Reassigning `self` is bad practice. Try having an instance variable `arr` and getting the elements of that through the [`__getitem__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627405/understanding-getitem-method) magic method.

Comment: look up the [python data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html), specifically `__getitem__`

Comment: also, reassigning `self` does absolutely nothing - except for having the local name `self` point at the list you created

Answer (score 4):

`THREEPOINTS` itself is not a list; it will have a list-valued attribute.

```
class THREEPOINTS:
    def __init__(self):
        self.points = [POINT(0,0) for i in range(3)]

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.points[i]

    def __setitem__(self, i, v):
        self.points[i] = v
```

Note the use of `range(3)`, not `range(4)`, to define 3 points. If you want your `THREEPOINTS` indexed from 1 to 3 rather than 0 to 2, you can subtract one from `i` in `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` to map your 1-based indices to 0-based indices used by the list.