# What exactly is pandas doing for this data slicing under the hood?

Tags: python, pandas, indexer

I'm trying to understand pandas, using it for data processing. I come from a C# world where all data filtering and manipulation is done through LINQ and anonymous functions. I've learned that with a data frame I can do something like this.

```
filtereddf = df[df['column'] == foo]
```

Which would return to me all the dataframe rows, where the column value is foo. What I'm trying to understand is, how is `df['column'] == foo` interpreted as an indexer? Is it treated as an anonymous function that is run every row, with "df" being a stand in for the row value?

Additionally, if I do `df[df['column'] == foo, 'bar']` I get a series of the bar column from rows where column is equal to foo. Is the logic used in interpreting  `df['column'] == foo` the same here, instead of returning a dataframe with a list of rows, it returns a list of values representing bar?

Comment: this should help: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding \_\_getitem\_\_ method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627405/understanding-getitem-method). Check out Cong's answer. Basically `[]` just calls this `__getitem__` method.