# The `[]` operator more than syntactic sugar?

Tags: python, cpython

The most common syntax of `slice` objects seems to be `int:int:int`, and specifically within the `[]` operator of `tuple`s `list`s and `str`s. It makes sense why this syntax can't be used to instantiate a `slice`,

```py
Python 3.10.4 (main, Jun 29 2022, 12:14:53) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 0:-1:1
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    0:-1:1
    ^
SyntaxError: illegal target for annotation
```

but when testing to see where the `slice` object is implicitly handled, it turns out to be in the `[]` operator:

```py
>>> [].__getitem__(0:-1:1)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    [].__getitem__(0:-1:1)
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> [][0:-1:1]
[]
>>> "".__getitem__(0:-1:1)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    "".__getitem__(0:-1:1)
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid synta
>>> ""[0:-1:1]
''
```

This seems to conflict with the common interpretation that `[]` is [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). What is going on under the hood of `[]`?

Comment: What do you mean by *"the common interpretation that [] is syntactic sugar"*? What is the evidence for this interpretation being common? `[]` is syntax, not all syntax is sugar. But if you want to say `[]` is syntax sugar for `__getitem__`, then you can also say that `[a:b:c]` is syntax sugar for `__getitem__(slice(a, b, c))`.

Comment: 124 upvotes on [the direct interpretation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43627489/14927325)

Comment: I suggest reading [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions) if you want 
something authoritative. The answer you linked to refers to Python 2, and does not appear to be meant to be taken literally as a specification for the meaning of this syntax; certainly, for Python 3 it is not accurate enough to be taken as a specification. As the docs make clear, not all occurrences of `[]` involve a `__getitem__` method; and `[::]` is a different syntactic form with [its own section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#slicings).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[]` operator creates a `slice` object and passes that to `__getitem__`:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3][0:-1:1]
[1, 2]
>>> [1, 2, 3].__getitem__(slice(0, -1, 1))
[1, 2]
```