# AttributeError: 'DataLoader' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: pytorch

I want to get the first image within Pytorch's dataloader as per this doc here: https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.datasets.CIFAR100.html

However I get the error in the title when I try doing this: `trainloader.__getitem__(0)`

Am I misunderstanding their docs?

Here's my code:

```
preprocess = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(256),
    transforms.CenterCrop(224),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
])

trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR100(root= "./data", train = True, transform=preprocess, download=True)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
trainloader.__getitem__(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the docs for a torch Dataset, which does in fact have a `__getitem__` implemented. However, you are calling `__getitem__` on `trainloader`, a DataLoader which does not have that method.

So this should do what you expect:

```
trainset.__getitem__(0)
```

When you get something from a Dataset, you are getting a single observation. DataLoaders should not be used to return single items in this manner; instead, they are for fetching a sampled *batch* of observations. That's why they don't support getting a single obs through `__getitem__`.

It's also worth reading a bit about how `__getitem__` works (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627405/understanding-getitem-method)); you can use it to subscript an object directly. `trainset[0]` is equivalent to `trainset.__getitem__(0)`.