# numpy where function TypeError

Tags: python, numpy

I need to find the Index of an 2D array, where the first Column equals 0.1. So something like this:

```
Data = [[0, 1], [0.075, 1], [0.1, 1], [0.11, 1], [0.125, 1]]
print(np.where(Data[:,0] == 0.1))
```

But then I get the following Error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Would be great if somebody could help me :)

Comment: Data is a list not a numpy array

Comment: You have a list of lists, not a 2D array. Try `Data[:][0]` or convert to `np.array(Data)` and then use commas

Comment: Is there a possibility to only get the index. Because now I get ```(array([2], dtype=int64),)```. But I need the index for ```data_origin_y = data[0:np.where(data[:,0]-data[0,0] == 0.1), 1]```

Answer (score 1):

The error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

is because `Data` is a list not a numpy array, notice that it says tuple because you are passing the tuple `(:, 0)` to the [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) method of `Data`. For more info see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627405/understanding-getitem-method), to fix it just do:

```
import numpy as np

Data = np.array([[0, 1], [0.075, 1], [0.1, 1], [0.11, 1], [0.125, 1]])
print(np.where(Data[:, 0] == 0.1))
```

**Output**

```
(array([2]),)
```

Answer (score 1):

just a typo.. you not initialised `Data` into an `array` it is in `list` form

**Code:-**

```
import numpy as np
Data = np.array([[0, 1], [0.075, 1], [0.1, 1], [0.11, 1], [0.125, 1]])
print(np.where(Data[:,0] == 0.1))
```

**Output:-**

```
(array([2]),)
```