# Is a SlackResponse object a dict or a string?

Tags: python, slack-api

Started using Slack API for Python, got comfortable using it from their documentation. I couldn't understand how this is working under the hood

Slack API returns `SlackResponse` object in case of a failure (or success as well), and it will look something like this

[image: slack-api-error]

Now if I run

```py
e.response["error"]
```

it prints `'channel_not_found'` message - as a `str` object

Thought `"error"` is a `key` (as in `e.response` as a `dict`), and tried to print all the available `key`s, but it's not a `dict`/`hash` it seems

```py
e.response.keys()
# AttributeError: 'SlackResponse' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Can someone explain how this is possible please. Would love to understand how they made this possible. TIA

Comment: The `SlackResponse` class (or one of its parents) must implement its own `__getitem__`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627405/understanding-getitem-method

Comment: Please give your question a proper name

Comment: Ironically, these `__`-methods are commonly called "magic methods"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Its always worth it to take a look at the source code, especially with python.

Here you can see that it returns a string, because the getter methods are overridden (`__getitem__`here), in case I understand your question correctly:
https://github.com/slackapi/python-slack-sdk/blob/main/slack_sdk/web/slack_response.py

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for taking time to look up their api and answer my question

Comment: Absolutely no problem. Please just try to give your question a more meaningful title, because people dont click on it otherwise.